# SSH issue with GitHub and terminal after push origin master

Tags: github, ssh

I am stuck with after statement "couldn't get a file descriptor referring to console".  I couldn't continue further than that.  I need your help on this issue. I am a new web developer and continue to learning to improve my skills.  Thank you for your time to guide me to right direction.

```
[ENV]:/vagrant/src/splurty $ git push origin master
    
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
    
[ENV]:/vagrant/src/splurty $ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/livestronger08/brolin.git
    
[ENV]:/vagrant/src/splurty $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    Agent pid 30162
    
[ENV]:/vagrant/src/splurty $ ssh-add
    Identity added: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa)
    
[ENV]:/vagrant/src/splurty $ $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
    $: command not found
    
[ENV]:/vagrant/src/splurty $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "derek.downie@ttu.edu"
    
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
    
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa): 
    /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
    
Overwrite (y/n)? y
    
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
    
Enter same passphrase again: 
    
Passphrases do not match.  Try again.
    
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
    
Enter same passphrase again: 
    
Your identification has been saved in /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.
    
Your public key has been saved in /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
    
The key fingerprint is:
    72:98:32:bc:e7:b1:05:0e:c6:99:17:3d:a0:00:6a:63 derek.downie@ttu.edu
    
The key's randomart image is:
    +--[ RSA 4096]----+
    |...   .          |
    |.  . . o         |
    |.E  . . o        |
    |o .o o + .       |
    |    X * S        |
    |   . B +         |
    |    . + .        |
    |     o +         |
    |      o          |
    +-----------------+
    
[ENV]:/vagrant/src/splurty $ eval 
    
[ENV]:/vagrant/src/splurty $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    Agent pid 30176
    
[ENV]:/vagrant/src/splurty $ open ~/.ssh/config
    Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
    
[ENV]:/vagrant/src/splurty $ touch ~/.ssh/config
```

Comment: As far as I know `ssh-keygen` doesn't generate a config directory, so the error message is expected. Did you add your newly generated key to GitHub?

Comment: No, I did not add a new generated key to GitHub.  I followed the step by step as instruction found on Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, it is going nowhere at this moment.  It seems like all my projects that I have been worked on have the same issue with ssh keys.    Therefore, I need to generate a new ssh key through GitHub?

Comment: `ssh-keygen` generates one private key in `.ssh/id_rsa` and one public key in `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. the public one needs to be given to github through settings->ssh keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the moment you have set the remote repository URL (with `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/livestronger08/brolin.git`) to an HTTPS one, every other commands related to SSH won't matter regarding the authentication.

The agent is needed only if you have entered a non-empty passphrase when creating the SSH key.

And the `~/.ssh/config` is a file needed only if your SSH key is not the default `~/.ssh/id_rsa` name. In your case, you don't need it.

Comment: Ok, I skipped the step #2 and #3 relates to keychain access.  Right now, I am adding a new ssh key to my github account.  I am coming across another problem here.  I am unable to copy the ssh key into to my github account.  I think the steps are confusing me right now.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: It shows that I am unable to add ssh key to my github account.  Due to no command 'pbcopy' found, did you mean: command 'bcopy' from package...   I am not quite getting it.  Can anybody guide me to the right direction please?

Comment: I finally solved the problem with ssh keys.  It's all good now.  Thank you VonC for answering my question about ~/.ssh/config part.  I will keep that in my mind for future reference.

Comment: As you mentioned that I have to skip the keychain access.  Therefore, I added the key to Github using:

$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

The output should look something like random letters, numbers, and special characters.  Then I copied the contents of the output to the key section on github.  It fixed the problem.  Now I am able to push all codings to the github now.  :o)

Comment: @Brolin Thank you for the feedback. And well done!

Comment: Thank you for your help as well.  :o)